# HummingBoard и Nitrogen6x kernel

Tags: linux, kernel

Всем привет, столкнулся с следующей проблемой.

Для запуска HummingBoard с другой платой B100, в следующей комплектации http://prntscr.com/7bsamz - требуется установка так называемого ядра Nitrogen6x. В интернете ничего подробного не нашел, либо не понял для чего это. 
Смысл работы этих плат, таков: К B100 подключается HDMI кабель с видеокамерой к примеру, с помощью gstream, получаем видео через HmmingBoard.

Comment: а в чём вопрос? upd. nitrogen6x — это плата.

Comment: как установить нужное ядро, чтобы b100 работала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

на [странице](http://www.auvidea.com/index.php/theme-styles/2014-12-30-22-32-06/b100-hdmi-to-csi-2-bridge), которая первой отыскивается при поиске строки «hummingboard b100», написано:

> If you are interested to attempt such a driver port please contact us for further support

вольный перевод: если вы заинтересованы опробовать этот драйвер, пожалуйста, обратитесь к нам.

на странице [контактов](http://www.auvidea.com/index.php/company/contact) написаны способы связи.

Comment: это не то, что мне нужно )